# Success without any errors shown anywhere but any data is not going to my database

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {

    $loggedin = $_SESSION['loggedin'];
} else {

    header('Location: ../login');
}

$user = $_SESSION['ID'];
$kuva = "Space";
$date = gmdate("j\.m\.Y H:i:s ");


include 'config.php';


$query = $connection->query("INSERT INTO rate(userID, kuva, rate) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$query2 = $connection->query("INSERT INTO picture(nimi, userID, rate, kommentti) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$query3 = $connection->query("INSERT INTO comment(userID, picture, date, text) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

$result = $connection->query("SELECT picture, date, text, user.username FROM comment INNER JOIN users WHERE picture = '$picture' LIMIT 3");


if (isset($_POST['submitPic'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['rating'])) {
        $rating = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rating']);
        $comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']);
        $query = array($user, $picture, $rating);
        $query2 = array($picture, $user, $rating, $comment);
        $success = '<span style="color:green;font-size:32px;">Success</span>';
    } else {
        $error = '<span style="color:red;font-size:32px;">Error</span>';
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['submitPic'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['comment'])) {

    } else {
        $query3 = array($user, $kuva, $date, $comment);
    }
}
$connection->close();
?>
```

**I get success after rating and commenting but any data doesn't go in to my database**

What is wrong with my code? Success without any errors shown anywhere but any data is not going to my database

There shouldn't be any problem with my database. It's just I don't see error

**EDIT: HERES MY HTML**

Here is my HTML

```
    <!-- Star rating -->
    <center>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <fieldset class="starability-basic"> 
                <input type="radio" id="rate1" name="rating" value="1" />
                <label for="rate1" title="1/10">1 star</label>

                <input type="radio" id="rate2" name="rating" value="2" />
                <label for="rate2" title="2/10">2 stars</label>

                <input type="radio" id="rate3" name="rating" value="3" />
                <label for="rate3" title="3/10">3 stars</label>

                <input type="radio" id="rate4" name="rating" value="4" />
                <label for="rate4" title="4/10">4 stars</label>

                <input type="radio" id="rate5" name="rating" value="5" />
                <label for="rate5" title="5/10">5 stars</label>

                <input type="radio" id="rate6" name="rating" value="6" />
                <label for="rate6" title="6/10">6 stars</label>

                <input type="radio" id="rate7" name="rating" value="7" />
                <label for="rate7" title="7/10">7 stars</label>

                <input type="radio" id="rate8" name="rating" value="8" />
                <label for="rate8" title="8/10">8 stars</label>

                <input type="radio" id="rate9" name="rating" value="9" />
                <label for="rate9" title="9/10">9 stars</label>

                <input type="radio" id="rate10" name="rating" value="10" />
                <label for="rate10" title="10/10">10 stars</label>
            </fieldset>
    </center>

    <center>
        <textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="4"></textarea>
    </textarea>
</center>
<center>
    <button type="submit" name="submitPic" class="submitPic">Send</button>
</center>
</form>
```

Comment: All you need to set `$success = '<span style="color:green;font-size:32px;">Success</span>';` is for `$_POST['submitPic']` and `$_POST['rating']` to be set ... *that's it*. It's not actually checking whether anything has actually worked or not.

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file reveal what the issue is?

Comment: `$query = $connection->query("INSERT INTO rate(userID, kuva, rate) VALUES(?,?,?)");` What do you expect this to do? Query doesn't use parameters, not that you're passing any in anyway. You need to use prepared statements, parameter binding, and execute statements. Here are the instructions for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont u use prepared statements.

```
$query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO rate(userID, kuva, rate) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$query->bind_param('iii', $user, $picture, $rating);
$query->execute();
$query->close();
```

Comment: Yes I realized this from @aynber comment and it is not working now. Thank you